# Json Serialize and Deserialize Multiple Object

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

The solution may be exist, but I tried few things online but i am not able to find relevant solution. Here is my scenario. I wanted to pass two models to Serialize(I user Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject) In order to send to my API. What I done so far

On the Client: I have mOrder (Order Model) and mOPLog (Log Model). Both I have combined in to one and Send to Json Serializer then to my API

```
 var data = new
                {
                    DataTable1 = mOrder,
                    DataTable2 = mOPLog
                };
                string sUrl = GlobalParameters.Host + "api/Order/UpdateOrderWithLog";
                string sResult = HttpHelper.httpPut(sUrl, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

Then on the Api Controller side I have declare Like this.

```
public Models.ApiResult UpdateOrderWithLog(dynamic data)
        {
            Models.Order model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Order>(data.ChildrenTokens[0].First);
```

Its throws the error when I deserialize and bind with my model. I can receive the Data on API Controller. Here is the data, how is looks like.

```
    {{
  "DataTable1": {
    "OrderID": "0000006915",
    "GroupID": "0000000001",
    "GroupCode": "WG01",
    "GroupName": "MatGroup",
    "ShiftID": "0000000001",
    "ShiftCode": "WS01",
    "ShiftName": "DayShift",
    "OrderDate": "2019-03-08T10:25:09.243",
    "OrderNO": "0000006915",
    "Memo": "Test123",
    "OrderDetail": [
      {
        "OrderDetailID": "0000007103",
        "OrderID": "0000006915",
        "SourceType": "IQR",
        "SourceID": "0000126061",        
        "Memo": "",
        "Accept": false
      },
      {
        "OrderDetailID": "0000007104",
        "OrderID": "0000006915",
        "SourceType": "IQR",
        "SourceID": "0000126062",       
        "Memo": "",
        "Accept": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "DataTable2": {
    "LogID": null,
    "LogType": "Update",
    "OperatorName": "admin",
    "OperatingTime": "2019-03-13T05:53:43.5940133+08:00",
    "OperationType": "Order",
    "Operation": "0000006915",
    "OperationContent": "",
    "OperatingSystem": "Win10",
    "TerminalName": "DH01",
    "IPAddress": "192.168.16.124"
  }
}}
```

But systems throws "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error" I am not sure, where I am making mistake. If anyone come across Json Serializing and De serializing multiple object. Any help will greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Update:** 
I Created a class with dynamic model, then send that one to API Controller.

```
 public class LogDyModel
{
    public dynamic m1 { get; set; }
    public dynamic m2 { get; set; }
}
```

on my Client i bind my model with this dynamic and send to my API Controller

```
Models.LogDyModel data = new Models.LogDyModel();
                data.m1 = mOrder;
                data.m2 = mOPLog;
```

On my API Controller

```
public Models.ApiResult UpdateOrderWithLog(Models.LogDyModel data)
    {
        var deserial = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.LogDyModel>(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
        Models.Order model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Order>(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserial.m1));
        Models.OpLog mLog = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.OpLog>(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserial.m2));
```

Now all is sorted as I wanted. Hope this will help someone looking similar issue. Thanks for the support whoever trying to check and help me out.

Comment: Your data is invalid json. You have extra `{ }`.

Comment: The JSON is not quite valid. Once the extra { and } are removed, you should be able to deserialize it to a "RootObject" type container containing DataTable1 and DataTable2 classes *without* trying to parse part of it at the same time

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain Again Yes. I can see one extra { } start and end. It is because the reason I have combined two models from my client and send to my API controller.  How to remove that extra '{}' on my API Controller. Can you please give one quick hint. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain I was reading through your comment and It took me while to figure out. The Reason I use dynamic, Because Each Datatable is one model and I dont want to combine and declare in my class or any where. Is there any method, just to parse part from my dynamic Data and bind with my existing model.  Thanks